# Pasar varias variables que estan en el href de un enlace con ajax a php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hola tengo la siguiente duda.. Quisiera enviar los datos que tengo en un Href de una etiqueta de enlace por medio de ajax hacia un php, la idea es que cuando le de clic al enlace, me deberia recopilar los datos del href para enviarlos al php... actualmente realizo esto pero solo capturo un dato el cual es el ID y me sirve para eliminar un registro... Alguna sugerencia o forma para realizar lo mismo pero pasando varios datos en el href? o alguna otra forma de pasar varios datos dentro de una etiqueta de enlace que funciona como un boton? anexo los codigos del ajax y php

Este codigo es el que realizo para eliminar un registro y paso solo un ID y funciona a la perfeccion

```
<td><a class="btn btn-danger eliminarCambio" href="<?php echo $res['idtabla']?>"><i class="fa fa-trash"> Rechazar</i></a></td>
```

Quisiera realizar lo mismo pero pasando varios datos en el href.. el codigo que tengo es el siguiente

```
<td>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo idtabla=" . $res['idtabla']."&tiporegistro=". $res['tiporegistro']."&idarea=" . $res['idarea']."&nombrearea=" .$res['nombrearea']."&descripcionarea=".$res['descripcionarea']."&imagenarea=".$res['imagenarea']?>">
<i class="fas fa-check"> Permitir</i></a>
</td>
```

El Javascript que utilizo para capturar el evento del clic es el siguiente

```
$(".eliminarCambio").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    
    Swal.fire({
      title: '¿Desea realmente rechazar el cambio?',
      text: "No será posible deshacer la acción",
      icon: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'Si , Rechazar!',
      cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar!'
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.isConfirmed) {
          enviaDatosCambio(id);
     
      }

    })
  });

function enviaDatosCambio(id){
  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET', //forma en que lo estas pasando
      data: 'idtabla='+id,  //parametros serializados
      url: 'services/rechazarcambios.php', // url del archivo q va a procesar los datos
      
      success: function(response) //si la respuesta es exitosa
      {
          console.log(response);
         Swal.fire(
          'CAMBIO RECHAZADO!',
           'Usted a rechazado el cambio.',
           'success'
        )
        setTimeout(function(){
          window.location.href = "cambios.php";//redirigimos a index despues de 3 segundos
      }, 1800); 

      }

  });
}
```

y el php que recibe los datos es

```
<?php

if(!isset($_GET["idtabla"])) exit();
$idtabla = $_GET["idtabla"];

include_once "../database/db.config.php";
// $sentencia = DBC::get()->prepare("DELETE FROM areas WHERE idArea = ?;");
// $resultado = $sentencia->execute([$idArea]);

try{
    $stmt = $conex->prepare("DELETE FROM modareas WHERE idtabla = ?;");
    $stmt->bind_param('i',$idtabla);
    $stmt->execute();
    if($stmt==TRUE){
    // $id_registro = $stmt->insert_id;
    //  if($id_registro>0){ //aqui valido si se inserta, hasta aqui todo bien
            $respuesta = array(
                'respuesta' => "exitoso",
                // 'idusuario' => $id_registro//realiza todo esto
           
            );
        
        }else{
            $respuesta = array(
                'respuesta' => 'fallo',
            // 'idusuario' => $id_registro
            );
        }
    
    
    $stmt->close();
    $conex->close();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "error ".$e->getMessage();
    }
    echo json_encode($respuesta, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme lo que necesito es solo saber como hacer que el ajax tome las multiples variables que quiero pasar por el Href para poder enviarlo al php es lo unico.. de antemano gracias...

Comment: Mi pregunta es: ¿Porqué usar el método GET para hacer cambios? ¿No sería más adecuado usar POST o incluso DELETE?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes extrar el valor de href y descomponerlo para extraer los parametros crear un objeto y de ahi manipularlo para enviar los parametros por AJAX

Por ejemplo:

```js
$('#link').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  let href = $(this).attr('href');
  let str = href.split('?')[1];
  let arr = str.split('&');
  
  let params = {};
  let pair = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    pair[0] = arr[i].split('=');
    params[pair[0][0]] = pair[0][1];
  }
  
  console.log(params);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link" href="/page?atr1=foo&atr2=bar&atr3=baz">
  Dale click
</a>
```